# Solve the following differential equaction in the sense of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have a following problem in functional analysis $$x^2\frac{du}{dx}=0$$ and I know I should solve it like this $$\langle x^2u',\phi \rangle=\langle0,\phi\rangle \Rightarrow \langle u, (x^2\phi)' \rangle = 0$$, set $\psi=(x^2\phi)'$, then $$\langle u,\psi \rangle=0$$
but then how can I solve $\psi$ in sense of distributions? How to prove it is a test function?

Comment: u is a constant distribution.

Comment: @ user40615 Yes, exactly. But I don't know how to solve it. I am stuck at here. I think I should prove that $\psi$ is a test function. and write it in terms of $\phi$ but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: I will try to write. Also it should be more than constant distribution.

Comment: Informally, the support of $\frac{du}{dx}$ must be (contained in) $\{0\}$. So $u$ is a linear combination of a) constants, b) Heaviside, c) derivatives of the Dirac distribution. Looking closer at c) shows that only the $0$-th derivative can actually occur, so $u = a + b\cdot H + c\cdot \delta$.

Comment: Why do you need do that user236625? You just put $u$ (suggested by Daniel) into the formula $\langle u, (x^2\phi)' \rangle=0$ and show that this is true for any test function $\phi$.

Comment: @user40615 I think a normal way to solve this question is to write $\psi$ in terms of $\phi$ and then solve it by substituting it into $\langle u,\psi \rangle = 0$, then I can solve it to get $\langle u,\phi \rangle$. I know what you mean, but that method is like I have known the answer, or I guess the answer is like this, and I test it. Even though it works this time, I still don't know what should I do if the question change to another one.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle u, (x^2\phi)' \rangle = \langle a+bH+c\delta,  (x^2\phi)'\rangle= a\langle 1, (x^2\phi)'\rangle+b\langle H, (x^2\phi)'\rangle+c\langle \delta, (x^2\phi)'\rangle$, where
$\langle 1, (x^2\phi)'\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x^2\phi)'dx=x^2\phi\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$,

$\langle H, (x^2\phi)'\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(x)(x^2\phi)'dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}(x^2\phi)'dx=x^2\phi\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}=0$, and

$\langle\delta, (x^2\phi)'\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)(x^2\phi)'dx=(x^2\phi)'\bigg|_{x=0}=0$. In computations we have used the properties of $\phi$ and $\delta$.